# How does a C++ compiler choose between deferred and async execution for std::async?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

It seems that the default behaviour of `std::async` heavily favours `std::launch::deferred`. I'm trying to understand why exactly the default behaviour seemingly never actually spawns asynchronous tasks. Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> task_list;

    size_t n_tasks = 10; // Let's say this could change at runtime
    // The first two seem interchangeable in this example:
    //auto launch_pol = std::launch::deferred;
    //auto launch_pol = std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred;
    // Only this seems to actually do async tasks:
    auto launch_pol = std::launch::async;

    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // Generate a bunch of tasks
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_tasks; i++) {
        task_list.emplace_back(std::async(launch_pol,
            [i](){
                std::cout << " Starting task " << i << std::endl;
                // The sleep is emulating, for example, a slow, I/O
                // bound operation
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                std::cout << " Stopping task " << i << std::endl;
            }
        ));
        // The following lines are experiments I tried to nudge the
        // task to start doing something.
        if (!task_list.at(i).valid()) {
            std::cout << "Task not valid!" << std::endl;
        }
        task_list.at(i).wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }


    // Wait for them to complete
    for (auto& task : task_list) {
        task.get();
    }

    std::chrono::duration<double> stop_time =
        std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_time;
    std::cout << "Execution time: " << stop_time.count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I've been experimenting with multiple launch policies. It seems that unless I explicitly state `std::launch::async` (only!), the compiler will fall back to `std::launch::deferred`. I tried this with Clang 3.8, gcc 5.4, and [this post](https://oopscenities.net/2013/01/04/c11-stdfuture-and-stdasync/)  seems to indicate that MSVC works in the same way.

OK, this is not in contradiction with the C++ standard. I get this is not a bug. If we specify `deferred`, we may get lazy evaluation, which is (in this case) pretty much the same as a serial execution of my tasks. However, what's the point if the compiler just falls back to `std::launch::deferred`?

If the compiler is always falling back to lazy evaluation, then calling `std::async` without `std::launch::async` seems pointless. I was hoping that the C++ runtime is smart about launching threads (or not) if I use the default launch policy.

Some background: In the problem I'm trying to solve, I'm running a variable number of initialization calls, which are pretty slow, but completely I/O bound (i.e., they wait most of the time for results from elsewhere). The number of these might scale, so I was hoping from some help from the compiler to schedule threads.

Comment: Having a little trouble figuring out what you are asking.  Are you asking why when using `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` the compiler chooses to use `std::launch::deferred` instead of `std::launch::async`?

Comment: *"If both the std::launch::async and std::launch::deferred flags are set in policy, it is up to the implementation whether to perform asynchronous execution or lazy evaluation."*, So you cannot assume one.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why does it choose deferred, and what's the thought process?

Comment: Note that using `sleep_for` with `async` is a bad idea

Comment: @o11c I was trying to emulate a slow function that is mostly waiting. Why is `sleep_for` a bad idea with `async`?

Comment: @Jarod42 The point I'm making here is that I *can* assume one, because it always seems to fall back to deferred. Question is, why, and when it does that.

Comment: @mbr0wn oh, for emulating it's fine. But, say, if you were doing a slow-busy-loop, the async dispatcher wouldn't know that the thread was available to be reused. But the C++ async framework isn't very mature anyway.

Comment: @o11c OK thanks, yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler vendors basically all chose to make "pick one" mean "deferred".

This sucks.

They are free to do any logic they choose.  They chose to make their logic be "always defer".

Comment: To be fair, "this sucks" applies to the standard, not to the compilers makers. They have two equally valid options, so they choose the one that takes the least effort. It's really the standard that, as usual, is complete shit because it works for _every_ platform (including ones that don't support threads) and in return doesn't work for _any_.

Comment: @damon compiler vendors could have chosen to generare a global thread pool equal to harsware concurrency count, and queue async's on it.  If you get before queue starts, run the task in the defer immediately.  As an example.  That would make the default async behaviour more reasonable than "always defer".  Maybe I'm missing something making this impractical.

Comment: You're right. A global thread pool would be the most reasonable thing (and is what most people who are not using `std::async` do). Thing is, this is extra effort, and the standard tries to be super general and thus _explicitly_ allows for something less complicated. It's the curse of being needlessly general and portable. Software using GNU autotools has the same symptom, it builds on every architecture including some that are only found in a museum, only just... on the exact system that _you_ use, for some reason, it never builds without trouble.

Comment: @Damon A compiler that simply implements the least the C++ standard requires is an example of poor QoI.  MSVC, gcc and clang *suck* here, their behavior is akin to using a assembly for loop of increment instructions to add integers (which is also permitted by the C++ standard).  They punted.  They failed to be reasonable.  The C++ standard permits compilers to be evil idiots; no reasonable standard can prevent that.  This is a failing of the major compilers, not the standard.