# Is it better to use the default launch policy for std::async with newer compilers?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

It is well known that the default launch policy may lead to deferred execution when using `std::async`. See for example [How does a C++ compiler choose between deferred and async execution for std::async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102206/how-does-a-c-compiler-choose-between-deferred-and-async-execution-for-stdasy).

I had seen this behaviour here when using MinGW-W64 with gcc 5.2.0. Therefore I have got used to always passing `std::launch::async` as launch policy.

Yet lately I have realized that newer gcc versions behave different. When using MinGW-W64 and g++ 8.1.0, omitting the `std::async` launch policy also leads to asynchronous execution in the code of the example linked above. Therefore I do not see a clear advantage of the `std::async` launch policy anymore.

On the contrary, item 35 of Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" seems to imply that the default lauch policy might prevent out-of-threads exceptions or lead to better load-balancing, if the C++ Standard Library implements a reasonable thread scheduler.

Is this the case? Should I therefore get used to sticking to the default launch policy? Is this the a general advice for all (relatively new) C++ compilers?

Comment: That's certainly the intention, but since some implementations' default behavior always falls back to `std::launch::deferred` (which they are allowed to do) they kind of ruin it for the rest of them. If you really want asynchronous execution (the code misbehaves if the function is deferred) and you really want portable code you then don't have much of a choice other than specifying `std::launch::async`. If it's a case of "ideally, this would be asynchronous" but doesn't break if it isn't, you can leave the default launch policy.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What do you mean with "platforms"? Compilers? Standard libraries? Or operating systems?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that as currently in the standard `std::async` is completely broken because it de-facto prevents thread pool usage AFAIK

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Changed to implementations. It's up to the standard library implementation what they do. They could conceivably be limited by the associated compilers or OS, though I don't immediately see how.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux AFAIK most compilers have switched to `deferred` because of the `thread_local` issue that blocks thread-pools. MSVC I think is the last hold out and they are planing on switching too IIRC.

Comment: @Mgetz Could you refer me to something that explains the `thread_local` issue you mention? My google skills failed me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux there are a couple of blogs but this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/462orv/the_promises_and_challenges_of_stdasync_taskbased/d02ly9j) makes it clearest. TL;DR; The standard requires the environment of a `std::async` task to run as if no other `std::async` tasks have run in the same thread. This has a really really nasty interaction with the `thread_local` modifier.

Comment: Oh I see, seems that `std::async` requires that the behavior is the same as if the function was run on a new thread. But to use thread pooling means that those thread's `thread_local` would have to somehow be re-initialized for every task or the behavior may differ from one you would get from a brand new thread.

Comment: I know that there are disadvantages of the Concurrency API, but for simple use cases I still prefer it much over plain threads. Isn't "completely broken" an invalid exaggeration?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler not really? it almost never acts or behaves in the way you want or expect.

Comment: @Mgetz What would be your alternative?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler depends on platform. On windows I'd use the CPP/winrt tools, on linux I'd use a wrapper around libuv. Those have very predictable and understandable semantics

Comment: @Mgetz Your answer is disappointing... but that does not prove that it's wrong! ;)

Comment: @BenjaminBihler The only good news is that the committee is well aware. I think they are looking into fixing it in the C++23 ish timeframe when coroutines are fully landed.

Comment: @Mgetz Boost also offers a `boost::async` now that uses a thread pool: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.executors. But the functionality is still experimental and here with mingw-w64/g++ 9.2.0 I have even compilation problems.