# Why do nested calls to boost::async block when using a thread pool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

I am trying to use `boost::async` and `boost::future` from "Boost.Thread" (Boost 1.71.0) as a thread-pool-ready replacement for `std::async` and `std::future` with Mingw (g++ 9.2.0). This would be great, since `std::async` has significant drawbacks (see for example the comments here: [Is it better to use the default launch policy for std::async with newer compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458371/is-it-better-to-use-the-default-launch-policy-for-stdasync-with-newer-compiler)).

I am using code where tasks executed by `async` themselves launch tasks. With `std::async` this has worked well. But now when using `boost::async` and a thread pool, my application gets stuck. The cpu load drops to zero, but the application doesn't proceed.

This example demonstrates the problem:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 5
#define BOOST_NO_SFINAE_EXPR

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/executors/basic_thread_pool.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Use three threads. As soon as the thread number is raised enough,
    // the problem will be gone.
    boost::basic_thread_pool threadPool(3);

    std::vector<boost::future<void>> futures;

    for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index)
    {
        futures.push_back(boost::async(threadPool, [&threadPool]()
        {
            for (int anotherIndex = 0; anotherIndex < 3; ++anotherIndex)
            {
                boost::future<void> future = boost::async(threadPool, []()
                        {
                            std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
                        }
                );

                future.get();
            }
        }));
    }

    for (auto& future : futures)
    {
        future.get();
    }

    std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now if I raise the number of threads in the thread pool (for example to ten), the problem will be gone. The application will finish successfully. This leads me to the interpretation that the "outer" tasks use the available threads in the thread pool. Then they start more tasks and wait for them. But if the number of threads is limited too much, their child tasks will not run, because the threads are blocked by the parents. Therefore the parents wait forever.

Is this interpretation correct? Why is it like that? If have not used thread pools before. Is this common for thread pools? Or is it a bad implementation by "Boost.Thread" (the respective code is still **experimental**!). Why doesn't `boost::future<>::get()` release its own thread for a while, if the task is not finished yet, to allow other tasks to use the cpu in the meantime? Is there a solution for that blocking? Is the solution a workaround or a commonly used pattern?

Comment: I would run it under a debugger and get the first hand accurate empirical knowledge. It probably takes less time than typing the post.

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately I reproducibly cannot interrupt/suspend the process of my example code when it is stuck (???). But when I interrupt my real-life code, I see that all threads are stuck within `boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait()` which is called eventually by some method called by `boost::future<void>::get()`. Although this is "first hand accurate empirical knowledge" and although it seems to support my interpretation, I still have the diffuse feeling that things like that should not happen with a thread pool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            future.get();
```

This blocks the worker that runs the current task. Since it waits for another task that, it will never progress unless there's a free worker in the pool to run that task.

The precise distribution of tasks is unspecified (it depends on platform scheduling and implementation I think here), it's easy to see that since you already post 3 outer tasks (saturating the pool), the inner tasks will easily encounter the situation that all workers are blocked on one of the inner tasks.

Comment: This answers the first two of my subquestions. But what does that mean? Is running sub tasks bad when using thread pools, because I can never know whether they will block? Or am I running my tasks in a completely wrong way? Or is there a common pattern for doing it "the right way"? Would it be better to post another question for that?

Comment: It's only "bad" if you the work isn't bounded/queued. In general tasks with dependencies can deadlock unless the scheduling is taking the dependencies into account.

Comment: There's not a "right" way. There are many possible common approaches. The simplest/most universally applicable one would be where the dependent task is posted as a continuation when the dependency completes (_completion handlers_ in the Asio world), instead of simultaneously.

Comment: My code base has several costly, auxiliary methods. I had intended to "silently" (the caller might be unaware of that) parallelize their work, but possibly these auxiliary methods may call each other. Your comments seem to imply that `boost::async` together with a thread pool is not a good tool for that, since the "outer" tasks should be scheduled after the "inner" tasks. But obviously the call stack order is the other way round...

Comment: Why not use coroutines, so the call stack order can match the dependency tree. And use proper queues for one-to-many dependencies (waiting for e.g. 100 independent sub tasks)